# How can I use a PostgreSQL triggers to store changes (SQL statements and row changes)

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging, triggers, auditing

Using PostgreSQL triggers, is it possible to record the changes that have happened to a table due to INSERT or UPDATE SQL statements and log them to a file for later execution.

This is only to be used temporally so just something quick and dirty would do.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

example of an audit trigger from 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    empname           text NOT NULL,
    salary            integer
);

CREATE TABLE emp_audit(
    operation         char(1)   NOT NULL,
    stamp             timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid            text      NOT NULL,
    empname           text      NOT NULL,
    salary integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_audit$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Create a row in emp_audit to reflect the operation performed on emp,
        -- make use of the special variable TG_OP to work out the operation.
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'D', now(), user, OLD.*;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'U', now(), user, NEW.*;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'I', now(), user, NEW.*;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_emp_audit();
```

Comment: Note that `TG_OP = 'DELETE'` etc. have to use uppercase `'DELETE'` etc. I had lowercased everything and was wondering what was wrong.

Answer (score 13):

Do you actually need the audit log of queries stored in a table? The easiest way to get a file with all the queries that have been executed is to use postgresql's built-in logging.

In your postgresql.conf (usually in the $PG_DATA dir), set the following options appropriately:

```
log_directory '/path/to/log/dir'
log_filename = 'filename.log'
log_statement = 'mod'
```

That last option makes it log all the  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, and COPY FROM statements.

More details in the Postgres docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Answer (score 12):

### SQL log

If you are interested only in the statements that are executed, then you can simply activate the PostgreSQL statement log.

For that, open the `postgresql.conf` file and set the following configuration property:

```
log_statement = 'all'
```

Afterward, you will see the SQL statements logged in a file under the following path:

```
$PG_DATA/pg_log/postgresql-YYYY-MM-DD_HHMMSS.log
```

However, if you want to record the row-level changes, then you need an audit logging mechanism which can be implemented using triggers, as follows.

### Database tables

Let's consider we have the following database tables:

[image: The book and book_audit_log tables]

The `book_audit_log` is going to store all the changes that happen in the `book` table.

The `book_audit_log` is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_audit_log (
    book_id bigint NOT NULL,
    old_row_data jsonb,
    new_row_data jsonb,
    dml_type dml_type NOT NULL,
    dml_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL,
    dml_created_by varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id, dml_type, dml_timestamp)
)
```

The `book_id` column stores the identifier of the associated book table record that was inserted, updated, or deleted by the current executing DML statement.

The `old_row_data` and `new_row_data` columns are of the JSONB type, and they will capture the state of the book row before and after the execution of the current INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

The `dml_type` column stores the type of the current executing DML statement (e.g., INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE). The dml_type type is a PostgreSQL enumeration type, that was created like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dml_type AS ENUM ('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE')
```

The `dml_timestamp` column stores the current timestamp.

The `dml_created_by` column stores the application user who generated the current INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE DML statement.

### PostgreSQL audit logging triggers

To capture the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE DML statements on the book table, we need to create a trigger function that looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION book_audit_trigger_func()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
BEGIN
   if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
       INSERT INTO book_audit_log (
           book_id,
           old_row_data,
           new_row_data,
           dml_type,
           dml_timestamp,
           dml_created_by
       )
       VALUES(
           NEW.id,
           null,
           to_jsonb(NEW),
           'INSERT',
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
           current_setting('var.logged_user')
       );
             
       RETURN NEW;
   elsif (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
       INSERT INTO book_audit_log (
           book_id,
           old_row_data,
           new_row_data,
           dml_type,
           dml_timestamp,
           dml_created_by
       )
       VALUES(
           NEW.id,
           to_jsonb(OLD),
           to_jsonb(NEW),
           'UPDATE',
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
           current_setting('var.logged_user')
       );
             
       RETURN NEW;
   elsif (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
       INSERT INTO book_audit_log (
           book_id,
           old_row_data,
           new_row_data,
           dml_type,
           dml_timestamp,
           dml_created_by
       )
       VALUES(
           OLD.id,
           to_jsonb(OLD),
           null,
           'DELETE',
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
           current_setting('var.logged_user')
       );
        
       RETURN OLD;
   end if;
     
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In order for the `book_audit_trigger_func` function to be executed after a book table record is inserted, updated or deleted, we have to define the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER book_audit_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON book
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION book_audit_trigger_func();
```

The `dml_created_by` column is set to the value of the `var.logged_user` PostgreSQL session variable, which was previously set by the application with the currently logged user, like this:

```
SET LOCAL var.logged_user = 'Vlad Mihalcea'
```

### Testing time

When executing an INSERT statement on the `book` table:

```
INSERT INTO book (
    id,
    author, 
    price_in_cents, 
    publisher, 
    title
) 
VALUES (
    1,
    'Vlad Mihalcea', 
    3990, 
    'Amazon', 
    'High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition'
)
```

We can see that a record is inserted in the `book_audit_log` that captures the INSERT statement that was just executed on the `book` table:

```
| book_id | old_row_data | new_row_data                                                                                                                                  | dml_type | dml_timestamp              | dml_created_by |
|---------|--------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------------------|----------------|
| 1       |              | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 3990} | INSERT   | 2020-08-25 13:19:57.073026 | Vlad Mihalcea  |
```

When updating the `book` table row:

```
UPDATE book 
SET price_in_cents = 4499 
WHERE id = 1
```

We can see that a new record is going to be added to the `book_audit_log` by the `book_audit_trigger`:

```
| book_id | old_row_data                                                                                                                                  | new_row_data                                                                                                                                  | dml_type | dml_timestamp              | dml_created_by |
|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------------------|----------------|
| 1       |                                                                                                                                               | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 3990} | INSERT   | 2020-08-25 13:19:57.073026 | Vlad Mihalcea  |
| 1       | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 3990} | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 4499} | UPDATE   | 2020-08-25 13:21:15.006365 | Vlad Mihalcea  |
```

When deleting the `book` table row:

```
DELETE FROM book 
WHERE id = 1
```

A new record is added to the `book_audit_log` by the `book_audit_trigger`:

```
| book_id | old_row_data                                                                                                                                  | new_row_data                                                                                                                                  | dml_type | dml_timestamp              | dml_created_by |
|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------------------|----------------|
| 1       |                                                                                                                                               | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 3990} | INSERT   | 2020-08-25 13:19:57.073026 | Vlad Mihalcea  |
| 1       | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 3990} | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 4499} | UPDATE   | 2020-08-25 13:21:15.006365 | Vlad Mihalcea  |
| 1       | {"id": 1, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence 1st edition", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon", "price_in_cents": 4499} |                                                                                                                                               | DELETE   | 2020-08-25 13:21:58.499881 | Vlad Mihalcea  |
```

Comment: What tool do you use for the UML and ERD diagrams you paste into your answers and blog posts?

Comment: As your columns are `jsonb` wouldn't it make more sense to use `to_jsonb()` to convert the records to jsonb instead of `row_to_json()`

Comment: That's a very good question. Even if the column is `jsonb` and I use `row_to_json`, it works just fine, as demonstrated by this [test case on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/b9631f1714828d002a9e8ff42fada3cfd87fabe8/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/audit/trigger/PostgreSQLTriggerBasedJsonAuditLogTest.java#L98). I'll try with `to_jsonb()` as well.

Comment: I tested it and it works the same with both `row_to_json` and `to_jsonb`, but `to_jsonb` should be preferred. Most likely a type conversion is done when using `row_to_json`, so I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The link below should point you in the right direction.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Depending on what you want to do, it probably is better to turn on logging.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL Table Log by Andreas Scherbaum is a Postgresql extension that uses a trigger to log any INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs on a specific table into another table.

The usage is easy: you create a second table which has the same format like your table you want to keep an eye on. Plus you need some additional columns to maintain the logged data.

The second part of tablelog is able to restore the state of the original table or of a specific row for any time in the past.

I haven't tried it myself, but it's supposedly working.

There's also slides from a talk about tablelog, but I can't post a proper link here due to some stackoverflow antispam weirdness :) (http :// andreas.scherbaum.la/writings/tablelog.pdf).

http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/

http:// andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/100-Log-Table-Changes-in-PostgreSQL-with-tablelog.html