# Postgresql 9.2 trigger to log changes to data in another table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have several tables and want to log when changes are made to them, what the change was and who made the change. Postgresql 9.2

```
CREATE TABLE unitsref (
unitsrefid serial primary key,
units varchar,
unitname varchar,
inuse boolean,
systemuse varchar,
keynotes integer,
linkid integer
);
```

Is the best practise to use OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.* ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_unitsref
    AFTER UPDATE ON unitsref
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_unitsref();
```

I am only really interested in the three fields:

```
units varchar,
unitname varchar,
inuse boolean,
```

I want to record these changes in a table eventlog with the fields:

```
recordtype varchar,
recordkey varchar,
changetype varchar,
personid integer,
changedate date,
changetime time,
changefrom varchar,
changeto varchar,
```

What is the best syntax to write a function to do this? 
In Progress Openedge I would write

```
create  EventLog.
assign  EventLog.PersonId    = glb-Personid
        EventLog.RecordType  = "UnitsRef"
        EventLog.RecordKey   = UnitsRef.Units
        EventLog.ChangeType  = "Create"
        EventLog.changeFrom  = ""
        EventLog.changeTo    = ""
        EventLog.changeDate  = today
        EventLog.changeTime  = time
```

but I don`t know the best method in Postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am only really interested in the three fields

Then it should be more efficient to only call the trigger after changes to these fields:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_unitsref
AFTER UPDATE OF units, unitname, inuse
ON unitsref
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.units, OLD.unitname, OLD.inuse) IS DISTINCT FROM
     (NEW.units, NEW.unitname, NEW.inuse)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_unitsref();
```

I quote [the manual on `CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html):

`UPDATE OF` ...

> The trigger will only fire if at least one of the listed columns is
>   mentioned as a target of the UPDATE command.

`WHEN` ...

> A Boolean expression that determines whether the trigger function will
>   actually be executed.

Note that these two elements are closely related but neither mutually exclusive nor redundant.

- It is much cheaper not to fire the trigger at all, if no column of interest is involved.
- It is much cheaper not to execute the trigger function if no column of interest was actually altered.

Related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7915100/939860) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547710/939860) ...

Comment: Excellent the WHEN expression is very useful - I wasn't aware of that. I`ve got about 20 tables that I need to log changes to so I have looked for a generic solution. I found this link which I will probably use and change the table eventlog to use the TABLE audit.logged_actions as per link. I was also wondering about saving the audit / event log in a separate schema as that would have advantages for me as well. Regards        https://github.com/ringerc/scrapcode/blob/master/postgresql/audit.sql