# PostgreSQL how often does a value changes

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a user table where I save the last connection oft every user. Is there a possibility to see how often the value changes? I can't add a new column for that because old programms use this table and I have fear that they wouldn't work properlly any more.

Comment: use trigger..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an update trigger that would log in another table each change.

Take a look at this: [Postgresql 9.2 trigger to log changes to data in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827694/postgresql-9-2-trigger-to-log-changes-to-data-in-another-table)

If it's acceptable for you (small enough number of SQL statemets executed on the server), you could log to a file all SQL statements executed:
[How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgres-sql-queries)

[Including csvlog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG) will allow you to import this in a table in (possibly another) Postgresql database, where you can easily filter statements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you completely, but you could create another table `logging` or similar and put data inside with a trigger.

Comment: I can't make any big changes to the database. Isn't there any posibility to see something like a history?