# How to log data change in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, audit-trail

This question may seem to be a possible duplicate of some other questions that are related to this topic. I've found some similar questions(some questions were asked years back and discussion on the topic seemed to be almost over). But no feasible solutions were found for my problem. I've a database with plenty of tables with huge amount of data in it. I need to log each and every changes that is happening to the datas that are stored in the tables of the particular database.

For example, I have a table for storing employee details.

```
id    employeename
 1    ab
```

And, this data is changed to

```
id    employeename
 1    cd
```

So i need to log this data.

ie, employeename

> ab

is changed to

> cd

in the table employee details

I need to log the data every time a change is made to the contents stored in the tables. Is it really possible? If so, how can I do that? What are the steps involved in it? I'm pretty concerned about the size of the log files in such a case. In such a situation what can be a good alternative? I'm using postgresql8.4. Any good suggestion will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to learn about triggers: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/triggers.html

Comment: Here is the example of a trigger, than logs such changes: [Audit trigger](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger).

Answer (score 20):

Very generic trigger function, found there: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/

Table to store the history:

```
CREATE SCHEMA logging;
CREATE TABLE logging.t_history (
        id             serial,
        tstamp         timestamp DEFAULT now(),
        schemaname     text,
        tabname        text,
        operation      text,
        who            text DEFAULT current_user,
        new_val        json,
        old_val        json
);
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
       BEGIN
         IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
         THEN INSERT INTO logging.t_history (
                tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val
              ) VALUES (
                TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW)
              );
           RETURN NEW;
         ELSIF  TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
         THEN
           INSERT INTO logging.t_history (
             tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val
           )
           VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD));
           RETURN NEW;
         ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE'
         THEN
           INSERT INTO logging.t_history
             (tabname, schemaname, operation, old_val)
             VALUES (
               TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD)
             );
             RETURN OLD;
         END IF;
       END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Apply the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON your_table
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_trigger();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I adapted it to my needs and it works well. I found out that I needed to save `session_user` rather than `current_user` when the function is a `SECURITY DEFINER` as the latter is the owner of the function, not the connected user.

Comment: In case of an **upsert**, say `INSERT INTO t (x, y) VALUES (x, y) ON CONFLICT (x) DO UPDATE SET y = EXCLUDED.y;` 2 rows are written in table `logging.t_history` with `BEFORE`. Using `AFTER` instead seems to be a possible solution if I haven't overlooked any issue.

Comment: follow up of previous comment : I hadn't seen this question: [How can I use a PostgreSQL triggers to store changes (SQL statements and row changes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295795/how-can-i-use-a-postgresql-triggers-to-store-changes-sql-statements-and-row-cha) in which similar solutions are proposed that use `AFTER`.

Answer (score 0):

The improved solutions as of 2024:

- **Trigger-based** https://github.com/iloveitaly/audit-trigger that uses JSONB with better indexing and querying performance, the ability to stop tracking by using `deaudit_table` function, etc.

Here is the gist of the core functionality:

```sql
/* Create a new table */
CREATE TABLE audit.logged_actions (
  event_id bigserial primary key,
  schema_name text not null,
  table_name text not null,
  relid oid not null,
  session_user_name text,
  action_tstamp_tx TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  action_tstamp_stm TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  action_tstamp_clk TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  transaction_id bigint,
  application_name text,
  client_addr inet,
  client_port integer,
  client_query text,
  action TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (action IN ('I', 'D', 'U', 'T')),
  row_data jsonb,
  changed_fields jsonb,
  statement_only boolean not null,
  row_id bigint
);

/* Create the main trigger function */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$
DECLARE
    audit_row audit.logged_actions;
    include_values boolean;
    log_diffs boolean;
    h_old jsonb;
    h_new jsonb;
    excluded_cols text [] = ARRAY []::text [];
    BEGIN IF TG_WHEN <> 'AFTER' THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'audit.if_modified_func() may only run as an AFTER trigger';
END IF;
audit_row = ROW(
    nextval('audit.logged_actions_event_id_seq'),
    TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::text,
    TG_TABLE_NAME::text,
    TG_RELID,
    session_user::text,
    current_timestamp,
    statement_timestamp(),
    clock_timestamp(),
    txid_current(),
    current_setting('application_name'),
    inet_client_addr(),
    inet_client_port(),
    current_query(),
    substring(TG_OP, 1, 1),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'f', -- statement_only,
    COALESCE(OLD.id, NULL) -- pk ID of the row
);
IF NOT TG_ARGV [0]::boolean IS DISTINCT
FROM 'f'::boolean THEN audit_row.client_query = NULL;
END IF;
IF TG_ARGV [1] IS NOT NULL THEN excluded_cols = TG_ARGV [1]::text [];
END IF;
IF (
    TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
    AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW'
) THEN audit_row.row_data = row_to_json(OLD)::JSONB - excluded_cols;
--Computing differences
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(tmp_new_row.key, tmp_new_row.value) AS new_data INTO audit_row.changed_fields
FROM jsonb_each_text(row_to_json(NEW)::JSONB) AS tmp_new_row
    JOIN jsonb_each_text(audit_row.row_data) AS tmp_old_row ON (
        tmp_new_row.key = tmp_old_row.key
        AND tmp_new_row.value IS DISTINCT
        FROM tmp_old_row.value
    );
IF audit_row.changed_fields = '{}'::JSONB THEN -- All changed fields are ignored. Skip this update.
RETURN NULL;
END IF;
ELSIF (
    TG_OP = 'DELETE'
    AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW'
) THEN audit_row.row_data = row_to_json(OLD)::JSONB - excluded_cols;
ELSIF (
    TG_OP = 'INSERT'
    AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW'
) THEN audit_row.row_data = row_to_json(NEW)::JSONB - excluded_cols;
ELSIF (
    TG_LEVEL = 'STATEMENT'
    AND TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE', 'TRUNCATE')
) THEN audit_row.statement_only = 't';
ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION '[audit.if_modified_func] - Trigger func added as trigger for unhandled case: %, %',
TG_OP,
TG_LEVEL;
RETURN NULL;
END IF;
INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions
VALUES (audit_row.*);
RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path = pg_catalog, public;

/* Create a function that dynamically creates a trigger */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.audit_table(
        target_table regclass,
        audit_rows boolean,
        audit_query_text boolean,
        audit_inserts boolean,
        ignored_cols text []
    ) RETURNS void AS $body$
DECLARE stm_targets text = 'INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE';
_q_txt text;
_ignored_cols_snip text = '';
BEGIN PERFORM deaudit_table(target_table);
IF audit_rows THEN IF array_length(ignored_cols, 1) > 0 THEN _ignored_cols_snip = ', ' || quote_literal(ignored_cols);
END IF;
_q_txt = 'CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_row AFTER ' || CASE
    WHEN audit_inserts THEN 'INSERT OR '
    ELSE ''
END || 'UPDATE OR DELETE ON ' || target_table || ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(' || quote_literal(audit_query_text) || _ignored_cols_snip || ');';
RAISE NOTICE '%',
_q_txt;
EXECUTE _q_txt;
stm_targets = 'TRUNCATE';
ELSE
END IF;
_q_txt = 'CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_stm AFTER ' || stm_targets || ' ON ' || target_table || ' FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(' || quote_literal(audit_query_text) || ');';
RAISE NOTICE '%',
_q_txt;
EXECUTE _q_txt;
END;
$body$ language 'plpgsql';

/* Call the function to create a trigger for a table */
SELECT audit.audit_table('your_table', BOOLEAN 't', BOOLEAN 't', BOOLEAN 't');
```

- **Replication-based** https://github.com/BemiHQ/bemi that allows capturing changes without performance impact, storing and scaling them separately from the main database, etc. (I'm the author)

Here is the overview of the architecture that uses [Debezium](https://debezium.io/):

[image]