# Tracking changes in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I m working with pgsql .I want to save the audit record to any file system(spread sheet,word...). ie, I have a web application. Any changes(insert,delete,update) occur in the app, will recorded in the audit logg table.But no of tables are in db also each table have more than 5000 rows. so it is difficult (bulk data)to save audit logg as a table.So I want to save audit log as a file in pgSQL. How can it implement?

Thankyou..

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295795/how-can-i-use-a-postgres-triggers-to-store-changes and here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veena.I have worked on pgsql past 2 years back.To my knowledge,To configure a PostgreSQL database as a standalone audit log database or to save audit file, just follow this.firstly Gather database information after that create the audit store schema and configure a PostgreSQL Server data source for CA SiteMinder and Point the Policy Server to the database finally restart the policy server.

You can create the logging schema so the pgsql server database can store audit logs.
To create audit logs,Open sm_postgresql_logs.sql in a text editor and copy the contents of the entire file and start a SQL client, such as psql, and log in as the user who administers the Policy Server database.Select the database instance from the database list and paste the schema from sm_postgresql_logs.sql into the query after that execute the query.

The audit log store schema is created in the database.

Hope this will help you.